# Qual é mais performático: "WHERE id IN (?, ?, ...)" ou "WHERE id = ? OR id = ? (...)"

Tags: mysql, query, desempenho

Não sou expert em MySQL, mas estou estudando e ultimamente estou tentando melhorar alguns códigos dos meus programas e me deparei com essa situação. Gostaria de saber se há diferenças entre as querys abaixo:

- `SELECT id, nome, email, endereco FROM usuarios WHERE id = 10 OR id = 11 OR id = 12;`
- `SELECT id, nome, email, endereco FROM usuarios WHERE id IN (10, 11, 12);`

É óbvio que a legibilidade aumenta significativamente e o tamanho da query diminui, reduzindo o tamanho do texto para o envio da requisição. Porém, além disso, há algum ganho em performance do lado servidor no processamento desses dados? O MySQL trabalha da mesma maneira em ambos os casos ou um pode ser mais rápido que o outro?

Comment: Já pediu ao MySQL o plano de execução? Eu **acho** que só vai ter diferença na hora de passar a consulta ao banco e no _parse_, mas o tempo de rede deve ser (por mais ínfimo que seja) menos irrelevante que o tempo de _parse_ dos caracteres extras. Estou escrevendo aqui só de intuição, não tenho base formal

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Bom, eu tentei visualizar algo pelo comando EXPLAIN do MySQL, mas o retorno nos dois casos foi o mesmo. Ainda não entendo sobre plano de execução, como eu peço para o MySQL essa informação?

Comment: Eu falo "êxtra" e você fala "éxtra" ;-) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-performance-explain.html